# How do I ensure that HDFS and YARN daemons run as different Unix users?

Tags: hadoop, kerberos

I am setting up Kerberos authentication on a multi-node cluster. The document says that the HDFS, YARN and MAPREDUCE daemons should run as different users. How do I configure it?

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the [Hadoop Security](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SecureMode.html) documentation as a first step to configure it.

You have to create different principals for all the services (namenode, datanode, resourcemanager, nodemanager, historyserver, etc) and then set the configuration properties as given in the documentation.

There's a lot to know about the complete implementation for hadoop security. You can google it for more documentation on Hadoop security. After then you can ask your question with more details such as what you have tried? and where you got stuck with exception and logs?

Comment: i just need to know that how can i run these daemons as different users?? Earlier when i was setting up my cluster  I created a single user and all the daemons ran as that single user. Now i need to run those daemons as different users.

Comment: Different user not meant for local users rather the user comes from Active Directory. You can install kerberos setup in Linux machine. I have tried with AD only. Then you have create many users in AD, then map it to principal and then have to create keytab. With the keytab you can able to authenticate with different principals configured for different daemons.

Comment: Does that mean I do not have to create different users?? I can simply install kerberos on my cluster and it should work??. Currently i have a user "user1" which runs all the services

Comment: If you use Active Directory then no need to create different users in the local machine, otherwise you have to create users in linux.

Answer (score 0):

Cloudera docs is not clear on this point. I had doubts as well.

So the way to go is:

1. Deploy Cloudera Manager, start a cluster. At this point daemons already run under proper users.
2. Deploy Kerberos.
3. Enable Kerberos via web UI.